# I am not Understand why error is come

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I want to match  password by enter user to database base password.Anybody Help me please.I am very Tired.

Adapter.java

```
    public Cursor getUserInfo(long rowId) throws SQLException
         {

             Cursor mCursor =
                     db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                     KEY_FULLNAME, KEY_EMAILID, KEY_PASSWORD}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId , null,
                     null, null, null, null);
                     if (mCursor.getCount()<1) { 
                         return mCursor;
                     }
                     mCursor.moveToNext();
                     String dpassword = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("PASSWORD")); 
                     return  mCursor;

                     }
```

Login.java
  Error come in this Class that tell to create the a variable dpassword.

```
loginbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // get the user details email or password
            String useremail = emailornumber.getText().toString();
            String password = userpassword.getText().toString();

            //fetch the password from the database
            String storedPassword = databaseAdapter.getUserInfo(dpassword);

            // check if password is match
            if(userpassword.equals(storedPassword)){
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "You are Login", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent in = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Username and Password Does not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
```

Comment: what is your problem???

Comment: You are trying to use a a variable named `dpassword` but you have not defined any variables with that name

Comment: instead of `mCursor.moveToNext();` use `mCursor.moveToFirst();`

Comment: is your code compile ??? `getUserInfo` return `Cursor` but you try get `String` in your code. change return value to String.

Comment: yes Kuffs that show the cannot resolve the variable to dpassword .

Comment: please tell me how to change return value in string

Comment: I was telling you how to resolve the problem you stated in your question. Use the correct variable name. The one you have used does not exist. You cannot use a variable named dpassword unless you first create a variable with that name  You also have other issues with your code but I am answering only the problem you stated in your question.

Comment: @Kuffs - so let's help the tired guy - please post it as an answer :)

Comment: I actually didnt think something that simple was worth posting as an answer but ok.

Comment: @Kuffs - well, we're here to help, aren't we? And as long as I can't make that 'dPassword' start blinking red, what other way is there to get the message through?

Comment: thanks to everyone.......   @Kuffs , 0X0nosugar , shayan pourvatan ,  M D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line of code:

```
String storedPassword = databaseAdapter.getUserInfo(dpassword);
```

is incorrect. You do not have a variable named `dpassword` and therefore cannot use that name. This is why you are receiving the error message you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Try Lik this ,it will Solve your Problem

**Calling the method**

```
String storedPassword = DB.getSingleEntry(email);
```

**Your Database Method**

```
//checking email to Corresponding password
public  String getSingleEntry(String email)
{
    Cursor cursor=database.query(DataBaseConnector.TABLE_NAME, null, " email=?", new String[]{email}, null, null, null);
    if(cursor.getCount()<1) // Email Not Exist
    {
        cursor.close();
        return "NOT EXIST";
    }
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String password= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Password"));
    cursor.close();
    return password;                
}
```

Comment: where you are error getting ,iam using this code in my app